# Rails ajax success event not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm struggling to get any Rails ajax event to fire.  I've tried boiling it down to the simplest example straight from the Rails Guides but with no success.

I have a page with the form:

```
<h1 id="title_line">Zone</h1>
<%= form_for(@zone, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div id="test_text">Test text</div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :operation, value: 'warmer' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Warmer' %>
<% end %>
```

The generated form code is

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/zones/2" class="edit_zone" data-remote="true" id="edit_zone_2" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
  </div>
  <input id="zone_operation" name="zone[operation]" type="hidden" value="warmer" />
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Warmer" />
</form>
```

In zones.js.coffee I have

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".edit_zone").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#test_text").append("Ajax success!")
  ).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#test_text").append("Ajax failure!")
```

resulting in the generated javascript

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $(".edit_zone").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
      return $("#test_text").append("Ajax success!");
    }).bind("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {
      return $("#test_text").append("Ajax failure!");
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

The controller update method contains (minus irrelevant stuff)

```
def update
  @zone = Zone.find(params[:id])
  logger.debug "* update running"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to zone_path(@zone), :notice => 'zone was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :ok }
    format.js { render :show}
  end
end
```

show.js.erb is simply

```
$("#title_line").append(" (a test)")
```

When I hit the form submit button, `a test` is appended to `Zone`, but nothing is appended to the `#test_text` div. The rails log shows

```
Started PATCH "/zones/2" for 75.67.229.139 at 2013-12-24 11:37:08 -0500 
Processing by ZonesController#update as JS 
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "zone"=>{"operation"=>"warmer"}, "commit"=>"Warmer", "id"=>"2"} 
  User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1 
  Zone Load (1.8ms)  SELECT `zones`.* FROM `zones` WHERE `zones`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1 
* Make zone warmer 
  Zone Load (1.9ms)  SELECT `zones`.* FROM `zones` WHERE `zones`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1 
 Rendered zones/show.js.erb (0.9ms) 
Completed 200 OK in 489ms (Views: 33.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.8ms)
```

So the show method is running (as shown by the `* update running` log entry), successfully rendering `show.js.erb` and returning `200 OK`. But the ajax events do not append any text to `#test_text`.  If I have `show.js.erb` append to #test_text, it works, so I know the ID is correct.

I'm actually trying to do something more complicated than this, but if I can't get this simple example to work, I've got no hope.  I'm running ruby 2.0.0p247, rails 4.0.0, and Safari 7.  I'd appreciate any help at all.

Comment: Does it also fail when you bind to ajax:complete?

Comment: It does fail.  I modified the event binding to look like

    `$(document).ready ->
      $(".edit_zone").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
        $("#test_text").append("Ajax success!")
      ).bind("ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
        $("#test_text").append("Ajax failure!")
      ).bind("ajax:complete", (xhr, status) ->
        $("#test_text").append("Ajax complete")
      ).bind("ajax:beforeSend", (e, xhr, settings) ->
        $("#test_text").append("Ajax beforeSend")
      )`
  
I even changed the appends to be alerts, but got nothing.

Comment: Have you checked the generated JS to see that it's what you expect? Also that you are binding to the correct element?

Comment: David, thanks so much for sticking with me on this.  I've added the generated HTML and JS to the question (to get formatting).  I'm not a JS expert, but it looks OK to me.  I'm working on single-stepping thru the Rails JS, but it's complicated.  Any debugging pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This problem may be caused by a missing `data {type: 'script'}`:

```
= form_for(@zone, remote: true, data: {type: 'script'})
```

This adds the `data-type="script"` attribute to the form, which uJS passes to jQuery's `ajax` method as parameter `dataType`.

According to [the docs of jQuery's `ajax` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

- if `dataType` is not specified if is inferred intelligently
- if `json` is inferred, the response is parsed into a Js object and returns a `parse error` on error

Answer (score 1):

Well, as expected, it's something apparently dumb I did.  I needed some pages to request a periodic ajax update and so used some code I'd found somewhere, putting the code in `app/assets/javascripts/common/ajax.js.coffee`.  Apparently that overrides the UJS ajax.js, which is where ajax event handling code is.  Deleting that file solved the problem.  But now the periodic ajax doesn't work well.  Oh, well.  Lesson learned.